# Como criar um método de pesquisa de datas?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu não consigo de maneira alguma criar um método de pesquisa de datas que funcione.

Já consegui cadastrar a data e os outros atributos também. Já consegui listar todos os atributos e também pesquisar todos os atributos tranquilamente, menos a data.

No meu código está assim:

**Cliente.java**:

```
Calendar dtNascimento; ...gets e sets
```

**ClienteDAOImpl**:

```
@Override
public List<Cliente> buscaNascimento(Calendar dtNascimento) {
    return em.createQuery("from Cliente c where "
            + "c.dtNascimento like :param", Cliente.class)
            .setParameter("param", dtNascimento)
            .getResultList();   
}
```

**ClienteDAO**:

```
public List<Cliente> buscaNascimento(Calendar dtNascimento);
```

**ClienteBean**:

```
public void buscarDtNascimento(){
    FacesMessage msg;
    List<Cliente> encontrados = cliDao.buscaNascimento(cli.getDtNascimento());
    if(encontrados != null){
        for(@SuppressWarnings("unused") Cliente c : encontrados){

        }
        lista = encontrados;
        msg =  new FacesMessage("Dados Encontrados");
    }else{
        msg =  new FacesMessage("Dados Incorretos");
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

**Página XHTML** (Primefaces):

```
<p:outputLabel id="dtNascimento" value="Data de Nascimento" />
                <p:calendar for="dtNascimento" mask="99/99/9999" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{clienteBean.cli.dtNascimento.time}"/>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{clienteBean.buscarDtNascimento}" update="lista"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recebi essa resposta de um amigo e resolveu meu problema!

Caso alguém esteja com esse problema, segue:

> Primeiro ponto, o `like` é utilizado para compração de String, logo, não funciona muito bem com datas.
>   Segundo, como está mapeado o atributo `dtNascimento` na sua classe Cliente? Certifique-se de usar o `@Temporal(TemporalType.XXX)` neste atributo para o JPA não se perder.
>
> Por fim, use a jpql a seguir:
>
> ```
> SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.dtNascimento = :param;
> ```
>
> ou simplesmente
>
> ```
> FROM Cliente c WHERE c.dtNascimento = :param;
> ```